How to set dynamic header titles in ASP.NET Core controllers using ViewBag
I'm working on an ASP.NET Core application and I have a base controller that defines a method to set a header title using ViewBag. I want to utilize this method in my Razor views to display dynamic header titles.
Here is the base controller with the SetHeaderTitle method:
public abstract class BaseController
{
    protected void SetHeaderTitle(string headerName)
    {
        ViewBag.HeaderTitle = headerName;
    }
}

In my derived controller, I call this method inside the constructor:
public class MaterialConstantNumbersController : BaseController
{
    private const string HeaderName = "Constant numbers section";

    public MaterialConstantNumbersController(IMediator mediator) : base(mediator)
    {
        SetHeaderTitle(headerName: HeaderName);
    }
}

However, when the Razor page loads, the header title does not display.
What could be causing the ViewBag.HeaderTitle to not display in the Razor view?
What is the best approach to set and display different header titles for each controller in my application?
I am using dependency injection for IMediator in my controllers.
The Razor view where I am trying to display the header title is set up to access ViewBag.HeaderTitle.
I have placed to call this method in all actions but this approach is not solid at all and it is repetitive work.

Can you please share a full [mre]?

1.It is not possible to call the SetHeaderTitle method in the  Controller Constructor, it needs to be called in every Action.
2.You  are using dependency injection for IMediator in your controllers.I think you have some mistakes.so I wrote  an example for you.
Here's an example：
1). BaseController.cs
using MediatR;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace webApi2.Controllers
{
    public abstract class BaseController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IMediator _mediator;
        public BaseController(IMediator mediator) {
            _mediator = mediator;
        }
        protected void SetHeaderTitle(string headerName)
        {
            ViewBag.HeaderTitle = headerName;
        }
    }
}

2). ProductsController.cs
using MediatR;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace webApi2.Controllers
{
    public class ProductsController : BaseController
    {
        private readonly IMediator _mediator;
        private const string HeaderName = "Constant numbers section";
        public ProductsController(IMediator mediator) : base(mediator)
        {
            _mediator = mediator;
        }
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            SetHeaderTitle(headerName: HeaderName);
            return View();
        }
    }
}

3).  index.cshtml

The result   is  as follows:

